# Build a URL using Python requests library

Tags: python, url, python-requests

I have a base URL.

```
BASE_URL = 'https://api.github.com/licenses'
```

I want to create a new url based on a search term(Ex - mit) appended to the base URL.

```
NEW_URL = 'https://api.github.com/licenses/mit'
```

I am using requests library to build and call the URLs as shown below.

```
from requests.compat import urljoin

base_url = 'https://api.github.com/licenses'
new_url = urljoin(base_url, 'mit')
print new_url
```

But when I print the new_url, it messes up the URL.

```
https://api.github.com/mit
```

I am not sure how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `/` at the end of the base url.

```
BASE_URL = 'https://api.github.com/licenses/'
```

Otherwise it's probably treating *licences* as filename.